# Zsh & RVM woes (rvm-prompt doesn't resolve)

Tags: rvm, zsh, zshrc

I recently saw the light and changed over to Zsh.  I naturally used Oh My Zsh to configure it, as I'm noobish. So, there are several themes that have an `rvm-prompt` included and here is were my problems began.  Everytime I load Zsh I have to `rvm reload` or else `rvm-prompt` is not resolved (`zsh: command not found: rvm-prompt`).  Note that it resolves fine after I reload.  Also, and in line, when I go to a directory that has its own `.rvmrc` (other gemset) and then I come out of it, the same problem occurs; I'm left with having to reload Zsh again.
I have RVM in `$PATH` set. I have

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in my `.zshrc`

I'm using the RVM plugin. Anybody know whats up? Not really a show stopper, just annoying.

Answer (score 21):

Make an alias to rvm-prompt. That's the most sure-fire answer. Arrange things in your `.zshrc` file in this order:

1. `alias rvm-prompt=$HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt`
2. `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`
3. `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

If oh-my-zsh (OMZ) loads before RVM, `which rvm-prompt` fails silently, so you won't see RVM in your prompt (if supported by your theme) even though it is in your path later, after RVM loads.

If RVM loads before OMZ, you may get a `zsh: command not found: rvm-prompt`.

Aliasing your rvm-prompt to its actual location seems to solve the problem, regardless of which order RVM and OMZ are loaded in. I'd still recommend RVM at the bottom.

Putting the RVM load into `.zshenv` as suggested above would load RVM twice in iTerm 2 (and no, it was not still in my `.zshrc`) and would result in the prompt displaying "system" even though `rvm-prompt` and `rvm current` showed a specific ruby version and gemset.

Comment: Good catch, jasongarber. It looks like the latest rvm tries to add ~/.rvm/bin to the path to do this, but it happens to late. As to your hint I moved the sourcing toward the bottom of the file. https://gist.github.com/1973583

Comment: Very nice catch yourself! Your way works great without the alias.

Comment: my rvm-promt returns nothing. but rvm current seems working fine.

Comment: This worked for me
`export RVM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm && PATH=$PATH:$RVM_HOME/bin`

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem until I put `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` into a `.zshenv` file instead of the `.zshrc` file.

Comment: This resulted in me seeing ‹system› in the rvm portion of my prompt even though `rvm current` reported otherwise. A better solution is to use an alias, as I describe below.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to get rid of it is to install RVM (Ruby Virtual Manager). You would then actually appreciate the theme.

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

The problem resolves itself after that..

Answer (score 4):

Not sure this will solve your problems, but it's worth a try anyways.

After a recent update to rvm, I had similar problems with oh-my-zsh. I uninstalled both rvm and oh-my-zsh then re-installed (install oh-my-zsh first, since it will copy a bunch or rvm paths into your `~/.zshrc` if you install rvm first).

Things worked a little better, except `rvm-prompt` wouldn't work right with a new terminal window. I wound up sticking the following at the end of my `~/.zshrc` and things work fine now:

```
rvm use default
```

I think some there is some kind of chicken-and-egg problem with the load order of rvm and oh-my-zsh with recent versions of rvm. Not sure which is to blame, but I hope it gets resolved by one or both of them!

Comment: the preferred way to do it is by moving to `.zshenv` as suggested by @johnernaut

Answer (score 1):

This problem is actually adressed in rvm's zsh-FAQ.

http://beginrescueend.com/integration/zsh/

adding 
    `__rvm_project_rvmrc`
to your .zshrc solves the issue.

I am adding this as an answer because I just found this while googling the issue and the above solution just sets the ruby version to rvm's default and does not work with gemsets.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Using the `.zshenv` as per answer above does.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to ~/.zshrc in

```
alias rvm-prompt=$HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt
```

Save

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Reference: http://xufei.logdown.com/posts/2012/09/09/zsh-rake-rvm-prompt